# Python: Read German/Spanish CSV files with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: python, csv, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a question regarding opening and reading a CSV file with encoded in utf-8 using Python. I spent most of the day browsing Stackoverflow topics and the Python csv module but I can't seem to find the right solution. My CSV file contains Spanish and German words with 'special' characters (ñ,é,etc.) , here is a snippet of my file:

```
english_person,spanish_M,spanish_F,german_person
woman,mujer ,mujer ,Frau 
strong,fuerte ,fuerte ,stark 
boy,niño ,niño ,Junge
```

Simply trying to read it with the codecs module doesn't work:

```
import csv
import codecs

f = codecs.open('file.csv', 'rb', encoding='utf-8')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for line in reader:
    print line
```

I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So, I downloaded the unicodecsv module and attempt to read the file like this:

```
import unicodecsv

myfile = open('file.csv')
data = unicodecsv.reader(myfile, encoding='utf-8', delimiter=';')
for row in data:                                                 
    print row
```

I luckily don't get an error anymore, but I still get these strange characters in my output (in the last line):

```
[u'\ufeffenglish_person,spanish_M,spanish_F,german_person']
[u'woman,mujer ,mujer ,Frau ']
[u'strong,fuerte ,fuerte ,stark ']
[u'boy,ni\xf1o ,ni\xf1o ,Junge ']
```

What is going on and how can I solve this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: That strange characters are characters like $,€,&,etc.

Comment: By strange characters in my ouput I meant the '\xf1' part in the last line, it seems to place the 'ñ' in the word 'niño'.

Comment: Check your CSV: 
there is no word "fuerte" in German.
 
Maybe you want "führte"  (past of "führen" [to lead])

Comment: `csv` doesn't directly support Unicode.  You shouldn't use `codecs.open` with it, but see the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#examples) module documentation (all the way at the bottom) for example wrappers that can handle Unicode.

Comment: ...doesn't directly support Unicode in Python 2.X, at least.  Python 3.X fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0

That's not a problem reading the CSV. That's a problem `print`ing it to the console. Your console doesn't support Unicode, so it can't print the U+FEFF Byte Order Mark character from the front of the CSV file. (It's common to put a faux-BOM in UTF-8 CSV files as Excel won't read them otherwise.)

The Windows console is essentially broken for Unicode from applications using the MS C runtime stdlib. [PrintFails](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails)

> I luckily don't get an error anymore, but I still get these strange characters in my output (in the last line):

You are printing rows here, not individual values. Each row is a list of strings. When you print a list it comes out in `repr` form, so your strings are printing in Python string literal form. `u'ni\xf1o'` and `u'niño'` are the same string.

(This is slightly clearer if you use the correct delimiter `,` rather than `;`.)